# Sample size in Pharmaceutical manufacturing

Tags: sampling, sample-size

Disclaimer: This is a very practical problem in the entire Pharmaceutical industry. Your response to this question may benefit entire mankind.

In Pharmaceutical formulations manufacturing (basically where your tablets and capsules are manufactured), organizations perform sampling to test whether specific characteristics of the tablets are within the specified range. For example, organizations would check assay of the active ingredient (the chemical that gets you healthy when ingested). Or Organizations would check the colour of the solution (COS). Some of tests performed through sampling are on continuous characteristics (as in continuous data) like assay and some of them are on discrete characteristics like shape and smoothness of the tablet.

Typically a tablet machine would take hours (let's assume 8 hours) to complete a batch. How does one design a sampling technique (sampling methodology + sample size) so that the sample size represents the population.

This problem becomes complex when
1. We know that the values of the characteristics being measured (example, assay) vary in that 8 hours duration, and 
2. We do NOT know how does the assay vary in the 8 hours duration (as in we do know if they follow a distribution or not).

Regulatory authorities like FDA and quality organizations like ASQ and ISO do not have a definite answer to this question (We have already looked at ISO 2859-1, ANSI/ASQ Z1.4 and Z1.9, ASTM E122, ASTM E2709, ASTM E2810 and did not find a solution)

If we can find an answer to this question, we would strengthen the sampling technique of the entire Pharma industry (provided the answer has not already been already and I look like a stupid to drop the question here) and ensure that the medicines that we, our family and friends take are definitely safe :)

Comment: I don't see a real question here.  The pharmaceutical industry and drug development is serious and complex and you seem to be mischaracterizing it.

Comment: I completely agree that pharmaceutical industry and drug development is serious and complex.

Comment: *Continuing* 
On the 'mis-characterization', let me rephrase the question. Is there an advancement in sampling methodology that can enable Pharma companies to do better sampling and thereby decrease risk for the patient? 
Answer to this question would go beyond the current practices in Pharma and possibly create a better approach (if at all there is one!) of sampling.